# Why can't we define a constant variable as static?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
public static const string Var1 = "abc";//compile time error
public static readonly string Var2 = "def";
```

Why can't we define a constant as static ?

Comment: Also, the idea that there is such a thing as a "constant variable" is self-contradictory.  "Constant" and "variable" are opposites.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Constants are already static so that would be redundant and are resolved at compile time.

For example:

```
const X = 5;
int a = X + X;
```

Basically ends up as:

```
int a = 5 + 5;
```

*However, the compiler optimizer will figure things out and actually emit 10.*

See here for more information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: They don't cease to exist - they're still part of the class, can be found with reflection etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahh really I always thought they got compiled out. Interesting to know.

Comment: Also you have to assign a value to a const at declaration and this cannot be changed, with a standard static variable the calue can be assigned at any point, so const int a=5;//fine a=20; //not allowed

Comment: @AliK Yeh, you can psuedo const a static with readonly though, can be useful for certain types.

Comment: Does same holds true for ReadOnly ?

Comment: @Brij readonly is read out from its original location when accessed. Its literal value is not embedded in code that uses it and thus it's the better choice for constants that might change at some point.

Comment: They never get emitted when defined inside a method, outside a method the const gets emitted but the value doesn't get referenced from the code. In above case it emits a literal "10" either way.

Answer (score 4):

A `const` field already *is* `static`.
Everywhere you use it, its literal value is embedded in the generated IL.
Adding the `static` keyword at the point of declaration would be redundant.

Comment: ah, so if a `public static readonly int` and a `public const int` are both referenced by a second assembly. They will exhibit different behaviour when values are changed if only the declaring assembly is recompiled with the value changes.

Answer (score 2):

From [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> Although a field cannot be declared as `static const`, a `const` field is essentially static in its behavior. It belongs to the type, not to instances of the type. Therefore, const fields can be accessed by using the same ClassName.MemberName notation that is used for static fields. No object instance is required.